# How to append XML file to another XML file

Tags: php, xml, model-view-controller, template-engine

I'm trying to create an xml-based template system. The idea is to return my views as xml files (xhtml) and then append them to specific nodes in a template xml file. The template xml is then transformed with xslt.

My question is: how do I insert these xml files into the template xml file?

Comment: You might find some thing here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377632/add-update-and-edit-an-xml-file-with-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [DOMDocument::importNode](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php) and [DOMNode::appendChild](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php).

Comment: related question: My views are php files with the content type set as text/xml. Would I be able to pass them into the DOMDocument/DOMNode classes as php files or will I need to use eval() first?

Comment: @Tun I don't understand your question. You don't pass DOMDocument PHP files, you pass it either a string containing the XML file or the path of the file (DOMDocument::load vs DOMDocument::loadXML).